# Can someone explain this odd javascript date output?

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, time

https://jsfiddle.net/8cvhnwgs/1/

```
//new Date(year, month, day, hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds)
$("#out").html(new Date(2015, 5, 31, 08, 25, 30, 0));
```

The date I give is May 31st, but it outputs July First, can someone explain why? Have I used arguments wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `month` parameter to the [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) constructor is 0 indexed, so 5 is June, which only has 30 days.

Comment: Ahh that explains it! Are any of the other parameters 0 indexed?

Comment: @user1032369 No, just one of them, to screw with everybody.

Comment: Classic javascript! Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Look at the [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date). The month is an integer value starting from 0 to 11.

```
new Date(2015, 0, 31)
// Sat Jan 31 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (UTC)
new Date(2015, 1, 31)
// Tue Mar 03 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (UTC)
new Date(2015, 2, 31)
// Tue Mar 31 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (UTC)
new Date(2015, 3, 31)
// Fri May 01 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (UTC)
new Date(2015, 4, 31)
// Sun May 31 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (UTC)
new Date(2015, 5, 31)
// Wed Jul 01 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (UTC)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 $("#out").html(new Date(2015, 4, 31, 08, 25, 30, 0));
```

5 is June, and since there is no 31 in June, it goes to July 1st.